# $S^1$ homeomorphic to $S^1 / \sim$ mapping is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle and for $x,y \in S^1$, let $x \sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are antipodal points of each other. So if $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta), (\cos \phi, \sin \phi) \in S^1$, then $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) \sim (\cos \phi, \sin \phi) \iff \theta = \phi + \pi$.

So we construct the homeomorphism $\varphi: S^1 \to S^1 / \sim$ via

$$\varphi((\cos \theta, \sin \theta)) = [(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)]$$

Where $[(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)] = \{(\cos \phi, \sin \phi): \phi = \theta + \pi  \}$ is the equivalence class of the point in question.

**How can I show that $\varphi$ and $\varphi$ are continuous?**

> Recall that in an identification (decomposition) space, a set $\mathscr{F} \subset S^1 / \sim$
> is open if and only if $\bigcup\{F: F \in \mathscr{F}\}$ is open in $S^1$.

To show $\varphi$ is continuous, let $\mathscr{F} \subset S^1 / \sim$ be open. Then by definition, $\bigcup\{F: F \in \mathscr{F}\}$ is open in $S^1$. We must show $\varphi^\leftarrow(\mathscr{F})$ is open. Note now that

$$\varphi^\leftarrow(\mathscr{F}) = \varphi^\leftarrow\Big(\displaystyle\bigcup_{F \in \mathscr{F}} F\Big) \displaystyle\bigcup_{F \in \mathscr{F}} \varphi^\leftarrow(F) = \dots ?$$

Is this headed in the right direction? What do I need to do to show $\varphi$ is continuous?

Comment: The quotient topology is *defined* so that $\varphi$ is always continuous.

Comment: @Randall But in this case, we are not choosing the topology on $S^1$ induced by the map. We are starting with the subspace topology and proving that the quotient map is continuous.

Comment: But what is the topology on your codomain if it's not the quotient topology?  Your map is definitely the quotient map.

Comment: @Randall Agreed, but it seems like you have to do some work to prove that.

Comment: You have $x \sim y$ iff $x = y$ or $x,y$ are antipodal.